# Dual \ when entering text inside text field

Tags: php, string, textfield, str-replace

I've got a simple text field where customers can enter their html/php codes.

On some servers all is working fine, but on some as soon as I type:

`\` it's saved as `\\`

So I wanted to remove it with such code, but it doesn't work:

```
$text = str_replace('\','',$text);
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Hmm. You need to start looking for differences between the servers. Your code, OS versions, PHP versions etc. There's obviously a difference between the machines that is causing different behaviors. Don't try to fix it with code. This should be be fixabe by matching the machines' configurations. And what do you mean: `It doesn't work?`

Comment: You have magic_quotes_gpc turned on. Which also implies some old version of PHP. Sort the cause, not the product of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for:

```
$text = str_replace('\\\\','\\',$text);
```

This replaces all `\\` with `\`, or:

```
$text = str_replace('\\','',$text);
```

This replaces all `\` with nothing.

The reason you need to use `\\` (and `\\\\` for two slashes) is to escape the `\`, since by itself, `'\'` is escaping the closing quote, making your string incomplete. So, you need to escape the `\`, turning it into `'\\'`.

The reason for this difference between servers is likely [magic quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc), and you can prevent code like the above by making sure both servers have the same value for this configuration entry.

And, after all that, you can replace this with just a call to [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/stripslashes), as [N.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693806/n-b) points out, and you will achieve the exact same results.

Comment: Also known as `stripslashes()`

Comment: @Spacedust: That's fine but don't depend on this as your final solution. Find the root cause!

Comment: @N.B. - True, but I wanted to explain it to the OP using the original code. I'll add that bit in though, thanks. (also, nice initials `;)`)

Comment: How to replace single quote or double quote with a correct character ? I got slash there too.

Comment: @Spacedust - I've updated my answer. You can either use the 2nd version of your code, or as N.B. pointed out, `stripslashes()`.

Comment: That's right. Some of our customers still use servers with old PHP versions like 5.2 or 5.3  that's why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

You always can use ascii codes:

```
 $text="\ it's saved as \\";
  $text = str_replace(chr(92),'',$text);
  echo $text;
```

return:

> it's saved as